# How to build an app that syncs when data is entered offline?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database

Let's say I build a todo app with an iphone app AND web app with some sort of centralized DB. If I add todos on my iphone without an internet connection, I will obviously not be able to see them on the web app. Since no API request can be made while offline, the data is not in the DB.

To prevent the tasks added while offline from getting lost, would you store them locally and then when an internet connection is established, then make the API calls to create these tasks and add them to the DB?

How exactly can this be done in iOS? Do I just build the object locally? How can you make it so that it knows specific tasks are not in the DB and should make API calls to make them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all your data in DB locally, and then check for internet connection is available or not, if internet is available, send the data to web by making API calls, then delete the data from local DB if u receive a response from server.
This way delete each row of ur local DB after getting response from server.

For This implementation you can have:

```
-  create a database on mobile
-  Register User on Server, After registering client should get a response from server and a timestamp.
-  Save timestamp and register a Pending Intent for 12 / 24 hrs to Start a Background Service that would Sync the Data to Server.
-  In case of no availability of Internet while Service wants to Sync data, we should have a Broadcast Receiver that check for internet connectivity, and as soon as Internet is available it would silently Start Service (Sync Service) in background and send data to Server.
-  Server would again send a response with timestamp, on receiving timestamp we delete our local Database, and repeat step 3. This cycle will keep on repeating.
```

I think this should server the purpose. In case of how to implement this leave a comment.